# Swift 4 Reduce problem: Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

Tags: swift, closures, reduce

I'm stuck with a

> Cannot use mutating member on immutable value: function call returns immutable value

error on this chunk of code:

```
var bagsToScan: [BagQR] {
    var initial: [Bag] = []
    return TaskManager.shared.tasks.value
        .filter({ $0.state == .ready })
        .reduce(initial) { (acc, task) in
            var bagQR = task.bags.filter({
                !tasksChecked.contains(BagQR(bag: $0, taskName: task.name).taskName)
            }).map({
                BagQR(bag: $0, taskName: task.name)
            })

            acc.append(contentsOf: bagQR)
        }.sort({ $0.bag.scanIndex < $1.bag.scanIndex })
}
```

The error is printed on the `reduce(initial) { (acc, task) in` line. 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: acc is immutable inside the reduce closure. Try `return acc + bagQR`.

Comment: Change sort to sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`reduce(into:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2924692-reduce)

```
.reduce(into: initial) { (acc, task) in
//...
```

That will make `acc` mutable.

And use [`sorted(by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted) on the result of that reduce.

```
.sorted(by: { $0.bag.scanIndex < $1.bag.scanIndex })
```

Comment: @Kwocs The code in your question has two errors: `acc.append`, and `.sort`

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you have any explanation that the error is prompted on the reduce line and not on `acc.append` and the `sort` ?

Comment: The result of a function is immutable. Trying to sort it in place is not allowed. It's right there in the error message `function call returns immutable value`